# How to change my scrapy from open each link from star_url to open my csv

Tags: python, scrapy

Before my scrapy used to do the following:
In each link of the top 250 from imdb it would open and would get the info that I needed.

Right now I have a csv file with 500 links and I need it to open one by one and get the information I seek.
However I'm a bit lost and have no idea how to do it.
I was thinking of changing the

```
def parse(self,response)
```

But I'm not sure how

This is my previous code:

```
import scrapy
from imdb2.items import Imdb2Item


class ThirdSpider(scrapy.Spider):
name = "imdbtestspider"
allowed_domains = ["imdb.com"]
start_urls = (
'http://www.imdb.com/chart/top',
)

def parse(self, response):
links = response.xpath('//tbody[@class="lister-list"]/tr/td[@class="titleColumn"]/a/@href').extract()
i =1 
for link in links:
    abs_url = response.urljoin(link)
    #
    url_next = '//*[@id="main"]/div/span/div/div/div[2]/table/tbody/tr['+str(i)+']/td[3]/strong/text()'
    rating = response.xpath(url_next).extract()
    if (i <= len(links)):
        i=i+1
    yield scrapy.Request(abs_url, callback = self.parse_indetail, meta={'rating' : rating})



def parse_indetail(self,response):
    item = Imdb2Item()
    #
    item['title'] = response.xpath('//div[@class="title_wrapper"]/h1/text()').extract()[0][:-1]
    item['production'] = response.xpath('//h4[contains(text(), "Production Co")]/following-sibling::a/text()').extract()

    return item
```

And my code is like this right now:

```
import scrapy
from imdb2.items import Imdb2Item
import csv
import re
from scrapy.contrib.linkextractors import LinkExtractor

class ThirdSpider(scrapy.Spider):
name = "imdbtestspider"
allowed_domains = []

with open('links.csv') as f:
    start_urls = [url.strip() for url in f.readlines()]

def parse(self, response):
    #this should change i guess?

def parse_indetail(self,response):
    item = Imdb2Item()
    #
    item['title'] = response.xpath('//div[@class="title_wrapper"]/h1/text()').extract()[0][:-1]
    item['production'] = response.xpath('//h4[contains(text(), "Production Co")]/following-sibling::a/text()').extract()

    return item
```

I added to get my links from csv file, but i dont know what to change on def parse.

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Do you have films links in your csv file? In this case your code will look like:

```
import scrapy
from imdb2.items import Imdb2Item
import csv

class ThirdSpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = "imdbtestspider"

    def start_requests(self):
        with open('links.csv', 'r') as f:
            for url in f.readlines():
                yield Request(url.strip())

    def parse(self, response):
        item = Imdb2Item()
        item['title'] = response.xpath('//div[@class="title_wrapper"]/h1/text()').extract()[0][:-1]
        item['production'] = response.xpath('//h4[contains(text(), "Production Co")]/following-sibling::a/text()').extract()
        yield item
```

Comment: Thanks, one more thing, that code gives me the production first instead of the title, what should i change?

Comment: Do you mean order in final dictionary?